# Squirrelmail ERROR Login Error

Tags: html-email, plesk, squirrelmail

I have been using Squirrelmail version 1.4.22 for over 2 months now and its been working perfectly.
Suddenly this morning users cant login and it gives them this error:
ERROR
You must be logged in to access this page.
Go to the login page

When i use an alternative mail client users are able to login into the mail accounts fine. I have tried to read online and even reinstall squirrelmail but still brings the same error and even within this forum and everybody seems to point it to a cookie issue. I have cross-checked by cookie session settings both on the server and browser and i don't seem to see an issue.

Please advise will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

Create php file in httpdocs of your web site with code:

```
<? phpinfo();
```

Check for value of session.save_path variable

Check for permissions on folder which defined in session.save_path:

```
ls -ld /path-to-folder
```

it should be 1733

Also check for errors in log file in

```
/var/www/vhosts/<your domain name>/statistics/logs/error_log
```